# Galaxy S2 Lite restarts when using 3G network

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, reboot, logging, 3g

I am using Samsung Galaxy S2 Lite running on Android 4.1.2. Using WiFi is fine, but if I use 3G, in some minutes the phone just **restarts** from nothing. It happens always near my house. In other places it can happens.

I think it is problem with my operator. I use the same chip in another phone (same model) and the same happens.

Is there any log (in `/var/log` or `/var/messages`) with some possible causes of this problem? Or maybe is it possible debug using the USB and some tool to identify why it is happens? Or maybe using DDMS?

Alternatively, how to fix it?

It is *very* strange, but I don't believe it is a problem of the device, but I can't prove that.

Comment: Have you tried using a different SIM card? It's possible the one you are using now is damaged and is causing issues with the radio that the phone doesn't know how to handle other than reboot itself. Especially since this happens on other phones with the same SIM.